# Microsoft Exchange - Registering an application for OAuth

Tags: oauth, exchange-server, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to use OAuth to connect to Exchange using their API. I'm not sure how to go about registering my application. I looked at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx), but the step by step link is no longer available. I need a valid authorization URL and token exchange URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a much easier OAuth flow that Exchange supports now. We've updated most of our tutorials to use this flow on https://dev.outlook.com/restgettingstarted (only iOS uses the v1 flow). Registration happens on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and is fairly straightforward.

Comment: I registered my app according to the tutorial above. I was able to make rest calls with the oauth token that I received. But I am not able to make Javamail store connection for imap. Does app registration differ for imap?